# problem to position a background-attachedment fixed

Tags: html, css

I have this website https://pure-cove-85477.herokuapp.com/courses
main problem I have with this page is that the hero image (#hero-courses) is not centered, I want to be able to position this image so that the text is centered in the middle of the bread, if you resize the page you will see that it centers perfectly because the background-attachment is relative and not fixed, but fixed is what I want.

If you check the 'Quienes Somos' or 'Home' section you will see it works perfectly with the same code, but I imagine is because of the image itself.

I have tried changing the background-position to any value but it doesn't seem to make any change. However, if I change the fixed attachment then the position is fine but is not the effect I am after.

```
#hero-courses {
    background-color: #fff; 
    background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/gnprojects/image/upload/v1548077551/Website%20images/hero_courses.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 70%;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 475px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #hero-courses {
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }   
}
```

Comment: try setting `background-position: bottom;` to `#hero-courses`.

Comment: works on mobile and small devices but in medium and large devices is not centered as I would like to.